# WD Hard disk stopped working while copying a file

Tags: hard-drive

I recently bought a 2TB hard disk about a month ago. Suddenly today when I was copying a file to it suddenly stopped working and started to make a noise. (It is similar to the noise hard disks make when it starts. But this just spins turning off and spinning again. (or the actuator makes it.. don't know))

So I restarted the PC and the disk was gone from the file explorer so I checked the disk manager. And this was what I greeted with (when I start the PC it made the noise for few mins and settled down)

[disk management mesg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flwsM.png)

I am not sure what should I do... will it erase all the data? There were some important data in that disk. Is there a safe way to fix this.

Comment: Sounds like you got one with an early hardware fail. If the data is valuable & you don't have a backup, I'd be more inclined to go straight to a data recovery company. Don't attempt to fix this yourself.

Comment: How does it show in the lower section of Disk management? (What size?)

Comment: If the disk is just a month old, see if it falls under warrantee and get it replaced.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I reached out to the store I bought the hard disk from and they said they will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

"Stopped working" and "making a noise" indicate a technical failure. Typically everything that is not partition table or file system related cannot be "fixed".

The only institution fixing things is the manufacturer himself after receiving defective drives.

Other fixes are done in recovery labs with the only purpose to enable duplicating the content of the drive.